# LibGdx What is the proper way to copy an Actor?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a custom implementation of Image that animates. I want to make multiple copies of an instance of this class using the minimum memory and processor time for rendering and copying. How do I go about it? Is it just easiest to recreate it whenever I need another one or is there some proper or suggested method for copying Image instances. I ask this because I can't find a copy constructor and I don't know if .clone() is implemented in Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to take care about Memory you can give all actors the same Image. But if you change the image in some way and at one of the Actors it does change at all actors with it(I did it with a sprite and changed the TextureRegion. All my Monsters looked at the same direction). But if you simply just have the same Image the whole time you can create your Objects and give all the same reference to one Image. 

For example like this:

```
public ArrayList<Actor> generateImageActor(){
        ArrayList<Actor> temp = new ArrayList<Actor>();
        Image img = new Image(____);
        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
            MyActor act = new MyActor(img);
            temp.add(act);
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

The rendertime does not get any effect if you refare to one image or to always a new image. I simply does take the picture and its offsett and draws it. So if you refare to 1 image at 10 actors it has the same rendertime else if you would have 10 actors with a copy of the image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I guess I could just create a function that pulls out the TextureRegion and copies it, you answered the question, but the code you posted wasn't really what I was looking for.

Comment: it shouldnt be exactly what you needed it was just an example what should help you to solve it. I dont know your code so i cant really create an example or code snip for you that solves your problem. Your idea should work with the texture region!

Comment: Yeah, not even close to answering the question, but good advice anyways.